# How to properly forkJoin a list of observables or their subscriptions?

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I have a very large list of ordered observables that needs to run in parallel. When each observables returns they append their result to a behaviour subject, which is how the results are passed on. However, I need a specific function to be called when they have all completed.

The observables each download an image (and related metadata), from an API. The requests need to be executed as fast as possible and I need to work with each result as it emits and emit an empty value when all the observables are finished. This means that the observables should be executed in parallel.

The original implementation, without a callback when they complete.

```
const requests: Observable[] = getRequests();

requests.forEach(obs => obs.subscribe(res => {
    const currentImages = this.$images.value;
    currentImages.push(res);
    this.$images.next(currentImages);
}));
```

In order to implement the callback when all requests have completed, I have tried the following.

```
const requests: Observable[] = getRequests();
const finishedTracker = new Subject<void>();

requests.forEach(obs => obs.subscribe(res => {
    const currentImages = this.$images.value;
    currentImages.push(res);
    this.$images.next(currentImages);
}));

forkJoin(requests).subscribe(() => {
    finishedTracker.next();
    finishedTracker.complete();
    console.log('requests done');
});
```

This works, but it seems strange to me, that I need to split up the forkJoin and subscriptions to the requests. Is there a better way to implement this functionality? I looked at mergeMap as well, but was not able to make it work.

**Edit**
Based on comments, I have realised subscribing twice means making the requests twice. Therefore I have attempted another implementation.

```
from(requests).pipe(
    mergeMap(o => {
        o.subscribe(res => {
            const currentImages = this.$images.value;
            currentImages.push(res);
            this.$images.next(currentImages);
        }
        return o;
    }, 10)
).subscribe(() => {
    finishedTracker.next();
    console.log('requests done');
})
```

I did not use the result from `forkJoin` because, as for as I understand, gives me the result of all the requests. Therefore it needs to wait for them to finish. Since each requests is relatively fast, but there are often hundreds of them I need their individual results passed to the behaviour subject as soon as each request finishes.

**Edit 2** The solution I went with.

```
from(requests).pipe(
    mergeMap(request => request, 10),
    scan<ImageResponse, ImageResponse[]>((all, current, index) => {
        all = all.concat(current);
        this.$images.next(all);
        return all;
    }, [])
).subscribe({
    complete: () => {
    finishedTracker.next();
    console.log('requests done');
}});
```

Comment: You are subscribing twice here, that can't be good. Why don't you just use the result return by the forkJoin ?

Comment: @MatthieuRiegler You are correct. I have added an edit explaining why I did not use the forkJoin result. In short, I want the results from the requests as soon as possible, so that they 'trickle' in to the behaviour subject as they finish.

Comment: After your edit you subscribe even more than before. You are propably looking for something like combineLatest as @MatthieuRiegler suggests

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not necessary to subscribe inside of your `mergeMap`.  In fact, as others have pointed out, it's causing a double subscription since `mergeMap` internally subscribes to the observable returned by the function you pass to it.

To handle the responses as they occur you can simply use a pipe and add your handling logic inside.  Since you are essentially doing a side effect (*something that doesn't modify the output of the current stream*), using the [`tap`](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/tap) operator is appropriate:

```js
from(requests).pipe(
    mergeMap(o => o.pipe(
        tap(res => {
            const currentImages = this.$images.value;
            currentImages.push(res);
            this.$images.next(currentImages);
        }),
    }, 10)
).subscribe(() => {
    finishedTracker.next();
    console.log('requests done');
})
```

---

While this will work, it looks like you are over complicating the observable flow.  I'm not exactly sure of your use case, but I'd guess the Subjects aren't really needed at all.  If your goal is to emit a cumulative array of results as they are processed, you can use [`scan`](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/scan) for this without involving any `Subject` or `BehaviorSubject`.  To do some logic when all requests have completed, you can pass a partial [`Observer`](https://rxjs.dev/guide/observer), that specifies only the `complete` callback (*instead of the `next` callback which is implicitly used when you pass a function as an argument to `subscribe()`*):

```js
from(requests).pipe(
    mergeMap(request => request, 10),
    scan((all, current) => all.concat(current), [])
).subscribe({
    complete: () => console.log('requests done')
});
```

---

EDIT:
As pointed out by @AdrianBrand, it's more concise to use [`merge`](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/merge) instead of `from`/`mergeMap`:

```js
merge(...requests, 10).pipe(
    scan((all, current) => all.concat(current), [])
).subscribe({
    complete: () => console.log('requests done')
})
```

Comment: Tap solves my issue, but in your simplified flow, each response is not passed. The problem is that I have hundreds and for some users, thousands of requests to make. I want to pass the partial response list or just the latest responses to the UI component while the entire list is processed.

Comment: Oh yes. Probably need to assign the observable and subscribe to it the way you were subscribing to `images$` previously. I’ll update when I’m back at the computer.

Comment: the use of scan actually solves my problem very neatly. I still need to pass the responses to another component via a separate behaviour subject, but this is much cleaner.

Comment: Is order important? This will not emit values in the same order as the requests were made. You may as well just use a merge. https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-9kukza?devtoolsheight=60&file=index.ts

Comment: Oh, you are right @AdrianBrand! `merge` is more concise instead of using `from` with `mergeMap`.

Comment: export declare function merge<T>(v1: ObservableInput<T>, concurrent?: number, scheduler?: SchedulerLike): Observable<T>; out of the 14 overloads this one looks like the one you want.

Comment: When using merge, I get an observable instead of a response in my scan. In my use-case I want to process the responses, so should I subscribe to them in the scan? Using `from` I can process the responses and subscribe to the `from` statement to both process the individual requests and report total completion.

Comment: Oh, the array elements should be passed one at a time into merge, not as an array. My mistake, I’ll update to include spread operator.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an expand that takes an accumulator that has an array of requests and the responses so far.

```js
const { of, expand, takeWhile, map, delay } = rxjs;

const requests = Array.from({ length: 10 }, (_, i) => of(`Response ${i + 1}`).pipe(delay(Math.random() * 500)));

const responses$ = of({ requests, responses: [] })
  .pipe(
    expand((acc) =>
      acc.requests[0].pipe(
        map((response) => {
          const [, ...remainingRequests] = acc.requests;
          return { requests: remainingRequests, responses: [...acc.responses, response] };
        })
      )
    ),
    takeWhile((acc) => acc.requests.length, true),
    map((acc) => acc.responses)
  );
  
  
responses$.subscribe((responses) => {
  console.log(responses);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/7.8.0/rxjs.umd.min.js" integrity="sha512-v0/YVjBcbjLN6scjmmJN+h86koeB7JhY4/2YeyA5l+rTdtKLv0VbDBNJ32rxJpsaW1QGMd1Z16lsLOSGI38Rbg==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```

Comment: But then I will only pass results on once they all finish. Each requests take less than 3-400 ms, but there can be hundreds of requests in the array. I need the results to be passed to the behaviour subject as soon as possible.

Comment: Then use concatMap

Comment: concatMap is also serial, according to the  [rxjs documentation](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/concatMap). The full request list will take over 5 seconds to complete and I don't want the user to wait that long for the UI to populated. 

I need the individual results to 'trickle' into the behaviour subject to populate the UI in more snappy fashion.

Comment: I edited the answer to use an expand that iterates with an accumulator of requests and responses so far.

Answer (score 1):

What about a simple combine latest ?

import { of, Observable, combineLatest, startWith } from 'rxjs';

```
declare const getRequests: () => Observable<any>[];

const requests: Observable<any>[] = getRequests();


combineLatest(requests.map(r => r.pipe(startWith(null)))).subscribe(result => {

  if (!result.some(r => r === null)) {
    // everything loaded
  } else {
    // not finished
  }
})
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzhAZgGjgeQEYGcCmUAbgIbYA2+GAxhCNsAHb4AyJM+uMGXJsA6sBgALOAF84KKHTgByKAA8AVrlkBuAFAaAJvmrk++OLUZc4Ac3wwASvgCOAV04xcALjgAKAJRwAvAD4sPEJSCnwAHhJGAE9-AG0AXU0NEzMoeycuNyCCYjJKSJj4hL8LK1tHZ1xvZJS6BmY2Di4PdMqsgDoQEjBWv0CoDrBgMHwPXgEhYQ9GB3JyL0WvDtwHPGooYGwx9NXyeADELTg4YBRPAEJduZgVuh3+uCg-X184WfnFo5OTgHpfuD4IiEaIiJjmODkCAkXTaDQnCT4cgEb4-f7vCDwFBMYC4YT4OEIjRiLxAA)

Comment: This is somewhat problematic since each observable will only emit once and there are hundreds of observables in the list. However, it might work, I will just need to find the non-null value in the result array as an additional step.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, if I understand you correctly, you just simply need to track multiple async http requests. You would like to "track" each separately and work with as soon as complete for each is fired, as also you need to track if all request are done and that's why you need to forJoin all requests. In that case I think your forEach + forkJoin approach is good, although as you said in edit, subscribing twice to http request will call to server twice, which is undesired behavior. I would just simply create another `Observable array` that sole purpose is to track completion of all events.

```
const requests: Observable[] = getRequests();
const finishTracker: Observable[] = [];

requests.forEach(obs => {
    const innerTracker = new Subject();
    finishTracker.push(innerTracker.asObservable());

    obs.subscribe(res => {
        innerTracker.next();
        innerTracker.complete();

        // Do whatever you want with your image responce
        doSomethingWithRes(res);
    });
});

forkJoin(finishTracker).subscribe(res => console.log('all finished'));
```

**WARNING!** Because subscribe is called in `forEach` loop, due to async nature of http req, I think that this may lead to undesired behavior of `forkJoin` firing complete or not firing at all, due to `innerTracker.complete()` firing faster than forEach ends populating array. In that case you will need to create separate array of objects before calling subscribe.

```
const requests: Observable[] = getRequests();
const additionalArray: any[] = [];
const finishTracker: Observable[] = [];

requests.forEach(obs => {
    const innerTracker = new Subject();
    finishTracker.push(innerTracker.asObservable());
    additionalArray.push({myObs: obs, tracker: innerTracker});
});

forkJoin(finishTracker).subscribe(res => console.log('all finished'));

additionalArray.forEach(myObj => {
    myObj.myObs.subscribe(
        res => {
            myObj.tracker.next();
            myObj.tracker.complete();

            // Do whatever you want with your image responce
            doSomethingWithRes(res);
        },
        err => {
            doSomethingWithErr(err)
        }
    )
});
```

You can move this filling process into your `getRequests()` function. This might be not the most elegant solution, but it works.

Comment: This is a good idea. However, I need to update another component each time a request completes and when all them are done, but your answer could relatively easily be modified to solve my problem